# Newtonsoft.Json Migration from version 6.0.3 to version 8.0.2

Tags: json.net, stripe.net

I want to use a third party library (stripe.net) that has a dependency in Newtonsoft.Json >= 7.0.1.
My system has few dozens of DLLs that has a dependency in Newtonsoft.Json, with a version that varies between 4.5 and 6.0.3.
Should I expect any problems upgrading to version 7.0.1? If there should be, what should I expect?
In addition, should there be any problem to upgrade it to the highest version of Newtonsoft.Json (8.0.2) instead of 7.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the up to date link on github. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases

Look for anything that says "change".  Many of them are minor changes and some of the changes are even non-breaking (changing signature method from abstract to virtual).  v9.0 doesn't even have a 'change' listed so I'm not sure why they even did a new major version there.  It doesn't seem like they follow semantic versioning.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently upgraded `Newtonsoft.Json` from *v7* to *v8* and I did not face any problems.

For *breaking changes* you should look [on the blog](http://james.newtonking.com/) and search for **Changes**. Everything listed under **Changes** might be *breaking changes*.

Comment: Shame there's nothing on the blog for v9 - Should check github for release notes which is up-to-date